# Typescript function that updates a known field in a generic type does not typecheck return value

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want to write a function that will update a known field of a generic type, this doesn't work and I am surprised that `Omit<T, "name"> & {name: string}` is not the same as `T`

```
 function  updateName<T extends { name: string }>(k: T, newName: string): T {
    const { name: _, ...obj } = k;
    return {name: newName, ...obj}
  }


Type '{ name: string; } & Omit<T, "name">' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{ name: string; } & Omit<T, "name">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ name: string; }'
```

What am I missing here?

Edit:

The larger aim of what I am trying to achieve here is updating certain properties of objects that have them with values of another type, for example turning `'firstName'` and `'lastName'` into numbers. Examples:

1.

```
{
  firstName: 'John', 
  age: 5
}
```

becomes

```
{
  firstName: 4, 
  age: 5
}
```

2. 

```
{
  firstName: 'John', 
  lastName: 'Smith', 
  age: 5
}
```

becomes

```
{
  firstName: 4, 
  lastName: 5,
  age: 5
}
```

The input type of this is `T extends {firstName?: string, lastName?: string}`.
The output:

```
type TT<A extends {firstName? : string, lastName?: string}> = {   [key in keyof A ]: key extends 'firstName' | 'lastName' ? number : A[key] }
```

So this doesn't type check:

```js
type TT<A extends {firstName? : string, lastName?: string}> = {  
   [key in keyof A ]: key extends 'firstName' | 'lastName' ? number : A[key] 
}


function nameToCount<T extends {firstName? : string, lastName?: string}>(k: T): TT<T> {
     const {firstName, lastName, ...rest} = k
     return { 
      ...rest, 
      ...( firstName && { firstName: firstName?.length || 0 }),
      ...( lastName && { lastName: lastName?.length || 0 }) 
      }; 
}
```

```
Type 'Omit<T, "firstName" | "lastName"> & { lastName?: number | undefined; firstName?: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'TT<T>'
```

Edit 2:

If the return type of `nameToCount` is left to be inferred type information appears to be lost:

```
const t = {firstName: 'potato', age: 5}
const t2 = nameToCount(t)
/*
const t2: Omit<{
    firstName: string;
    age: number;
}, "firstName" | "lastName"> & {
    lastName?: number | undefined;
    firstName?: number | undefined;
}
*/
```

Comment: I think  easiest is to just *override* the property by re-declaring it, or am I missing something? Check out this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCADgEwIZQKYDkMC22APACqLYAeOYaAzogN6JiHYBcidUATjGAHNEAXwB8ACgDWnUgBoW2AO74inbn0EBKGUwBQiRD2xQQPJMwB0VyfKsXmrVQuVsRIgNy7hu3RAR04ABtsC0C4AXFUTBwVbHEHNk4AIgApOGwkkXlUuAALMCTNTU8gA).

Comment: You're missing that `string` might not be specific enough for the `T["name"]` property, as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WyVv6w). Does that fully address the question (which is, as far as I can tell, "what am I missing")? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what remains unanswered?

Comment: I realise now that my question is not that clear as to what I am trying to achieve. @jcalz that is a good explanation, I understand now, how can I fix that?. Ultimately my goal is to also update the type of the name and to return some transformed type: `type TT<A extends {name : string}> = {
  [key in keyof A ]: key extends 'name' ? number : A[key]
}`

Comment: This is what I am trying to make work: ```type TT<A extends {name : string}> = {
  [key in keyof A ]: key extends 'name' ? number : A[key]
}
function updateName2<T extends { name: string }>(k: T, newName: number): TT<T> {
  return { ...k, ...{ name: newName } };
}```

Comment: ① You're still not explicitly asking a question other than "what am I missing", except for in the comments. Could you please [edit] to ask exactly the question whose answer you need? ② Your updated use case seems significantly different, since now you are *intentionally* changing the property type. Not just string-to-string, but string-to-number. If that's the use case, could you fix the code to be a single [mre] of it?

Comment: ③ If you're trying to make it work, what specifically is wrong with using the inferred output type as opposed to trying to force the compiler to accept that it's assignable to `TT<T>`? If you look at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wE2V2N), it works as expected, I'd think. Why do you require something else? Please show it with code.

Comment: @jcalz once a value goes through this function type information is lost [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGAhgWwKYBU4GE7hQA8WiGAHlBmACYDOiA3sDAE51QBy6GA-IgC5EHVjDABzADSIANig7dMvISLHiAvgD4AFAGshWAJRMAUInPmICDkxbsuPaXIWPEAOg+sMHdYgC8iLpmFoheUCCsSIyIwSEebl4c0rEW8dqIdi6YiABkOUwZbFkYQpkOSm4y1OJQABaIAD4NiAAMiOqGkinmabLy5Ri5+dHOA0KjinyV1XWNzW0dMSHm6gDcMeomJlZgNlD+tkVjiADkAA5wUChQcCfSKOIliACsmzt7AEwHqJg4+ITaKCGEwAegAVNtrPsoB8hAB5NAwYiMFJlSYqKCiCSrFIPJ5gEBoABGGFYOPU0gARGieJTGohKRNaZpcqYQkylEICcTSfTwDQMCwwBgaDiQjTOchCSTWHzaIKxCLySYwSCgA)

Comment: Hmm, but that has very little to do with the problem as originally stated, and has much to do with expecting to compiler to follow the logic of `...( firstName && { firstName: firstName?.length || 0 })` as a function of the generic type of `T`.  I fear that as time goes on the scope of the question is getting less clear and not more clear, so I'm going to have to disengage now. If you [edit] the question to rephrase it as a single explicit concise question with a [mre] and not a series of chronological updates, I'll take another look. Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: That is fair, thanks @jcalz